# Ext.form.field.File disable button

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have the following filefield:

```
{
    xtype: 'filefield',
    name: 'photo',
    fieldLabel: 'Photo',
    labelWidth: 50,
    allowBlank: false,
    buttonText: 'Select Photo...'
}
```

I try to disable the button of the filefield with:

```
if (f instanceof Ext.form.field.File) { //f is a field in my form
    f.button.setDisabled(true)
}
```

This works like I expect visually but after I enable this button the handler of the button does not get called anymore.
I can hear you think *Why don't you call `setDisabled()` on the field?* .. because the form won't submit its value if the field is disabled. And I implemented my own way of disabling items with CSS.

My question is: **How can I disable the button of a** `filefield` **in ExtJS 4.1.2?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be [a bug](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?242022) in ExtJs 4.1.

This is resolved in version ExtJS 4.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Why not putting a small mask on the button? It could be controlled manually.

Comment: Are you referring to [maskOnDisable](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-property-maskOnDisable)?